# Django Pass a Form's Field to a Model's Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning Django web framework by going through [this](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial) example. In one of the view [functions](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/02132ec8edf86af30fd86dc6ad26066810ad5a5f/catalog/views.py#L96):

```
def renew_book_librarian(request, pk):
    """View function for renewing a specific BookInstance by librarian."""
    book_instance = get_object_or_404(BookInstance, pk=pk)

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = RenewBookForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
            book_instance.due_back = form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']
            book_instance.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-borrowed'))

    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form
    else:
        proposed_renewal_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
        form = RenewBookForm(initial={'renewal_date': proposed_renewal_date})

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'book_instance': book_instance,
    }

    return render(request, 'catalog/book_renew_librarian.html', context)
```

It assigns `form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']` to `book_instance.due_back`. However, `form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']` is not a `models.DateField` as defined by the [BookInstance](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/02132ec8edf86af30fd86dc6ad26066810ad5a5f/catalog/models.py#L76) class:

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library)."""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID for this particular book across whole library")
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

So how is this assignment possible?

**Update**:
It seems like Django converts `book_instance.due_back` from `models.DateField` to Python's `datetime.date`, which makes the assignment possible. When and how does this translation occur? Any pointers to Django's codebase?

Comment: But the [**`RenewBookForm.renewal_date`**](https://github.com/mdn/django-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/02132ec8edf86af30fd86dc6ad26066810ad5a5f/catalog/forms.py#L10) field is a ***DateField***

Comment: Thanks @JPG! While this is true, it is a `form.DataField` but not a `models.DataField` -- how are they interchangeable? Also, I am not sure `form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']` returns a `form.DataField` though. Any pointers to relevant Django code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481713/whats-the-difference-between-django-models-and-forms

Comment: I don't think your link answers the question at all. In fact, it says the opposite, i.e., a form and a model **are** indeed different so a form's DataField is not the same as a model's.

Comment: I didn't say that, did I?

Comment: No. But that link didn't answer my question, nor did it clarify anything relevant to my question. As a result, I am not sure the purpose of you giving the link here?